# Can you transfer pictures from Facebook to Tumblr?

Tags: facebook, tumblr

I would like to put some pictures from Facebook directly on my Tumblr, is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't quite tell from your question whether you're looking to do this retroactively or not, but but one easy solution for this going forward is to use a service such as [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) (stands for If This Then That). You can add both facebook and tumblr as 'channels' and then use a recipe such as this one:
[FB Image to Tumblr Photo Post](https://ifttt.com/recipes/8557)

IFTTT is completely free, and I am in no way affiliated with them (other than being an avid user).